# Share Version across the azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have multiple pipelines for different branches (development, staging and production). We need to manage version as major.minor.patch across the pipeplies.

Using counter expression, it is possible for single pipeline. for example, dev pipeline has `2.3.9`,  staging has `2.3.0` and production has `2.2.0`.

If I trigger build for production version should be `2.3.10`

Tried with Group Variable in Library for managing major, minor and patch in Global scope. But pipeline does not allow arithmetic operation (increment) using scripts.

How can I achive versioning across the pipelines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use something like GitVersion to auto-increment versions based on repository tags instead of trying to build your own home-grown method of achieving the same thing. Also consider adopting a simpler branching strategy in which you don't maintain different branches per environment\

Comment: @ahnirab Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you need to share the version between pipelines.

The current pipeline can be incremented by the version number of the previous pipeline run.

The counter expression can not share the version between multiple pipelines. It can only work on the current Pipeline.

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can keep using the Variable Group to save the version number and share them between the Pipelines.

In this case, you can use script to increment the version number, then you can save the updated version number to Variable Group via Rest API: [Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

Here is Pipeline example: Use PowerShell Script to update version number and save it to Variable Group.

YAML sample:

```
variables:
- group: version

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $major = $(major)
      $minor = $(minor)
      $patch = $(patch)
      echo $major
      echo $minor
      echo $patch
      
      #Update Patch Number
      
      $Updatepatch = [int]$patch + 1
      echo $Updatepatch
      $version = "$major.$minor.$Updatepatch"
      
      echo $version
    
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$version"

      $token = "$(PAT)"
      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{Project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{VariableGroupId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
      
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = @"
      {
        
          "variables": {
              "major": {
                  "value": "$major"
              },
              "minor": {
                  "value": "$minor"
              },
              "patch": {
                  "value": "$patch"
              }
          },
        "type": "Vsts",
        "name": "Version",
        "description": "Updated variable group"
      
      }
      "@
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
  

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo $(version)'
```

We can use the [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#about-tasksetvariable) to set the Pipeline variable. Then we can use the variable: **$(version)** in the next tasks.

Result:

Variable Group: Before running Pipeline

[image]

Variable Group: After running Pipeline

[image]

Pipeline log:

[image]